# Centering cells in a LabelFrame using grid()

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I center all rows and columns within a LabelFrame in Tkinter using the grid geometry manager? By default, everything is centered in their cells, but how can I center the cells in a LabelFrame if that LabelFrame has a set height and width?

For example:

```
self.labelframe = Labelframe(self, text="First Labelframe",height=200, width=200)
self.labelframe.pack()

self.label1 = Label(self.labelframe, text="Label1")
self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

self.label2 = Label(self.labelframe, text="Label2")
self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)

self.label3 = Label(self.labelframe, text="Label3")
self.label3.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

In this example the labels with be centered in their cells but the cells will start at the top left of the LabelFrame. Is there a way I can center the cells?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to add an empty row at the top and bottom, and an empty column on the left and right. Give these rows and columns a weight so that any extra space is given to them.

```
self.label1.grid(row=1, column=1)
self.label2.grid(row=1, column=2)
self.label3.grid(row=2, column=1)

self.labelframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.labelframe.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
self.labelframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.labelframe.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
```

Another solution is to add another frame that surrounds `self.labelframe`. You can then let `self.labelframe` remain the size that it wants, but have it centered in this other frame.

Comment: If I wanted to move the cells to the right, could I just add an empty cell in the first row and use `weight` to push the cells over to the center of the LabelFrame?